# Can i install Ubuntu 13.10 64bit on my Lanovo g580 Laptop

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have a Lenovo G580 i5 Processor, 8GB Ram and 500GB HDD. I have already installed Windows 8 64-Bit Operating System and I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 64-Bit with dual boot.

What should the BIOS settings be before installing? Ubuntu UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular Ubuntu DVD and select dual-boot during install. Use the 64-bit version. The boot options will appear automatically when you're done.

Comment: Thanks as per your comment i have install dual booting but when i install Ubuntu with Win 8.. it shows "found no operating system"

Comment: and when i install it through Something Else use partition...i am unable to boot my Windows 8 pls help.